# AES-256-CBC Bad Decrypt

Tags: node.js, cryptography

## Step 1: Create key with `pbkdf2`

```
var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('prancypoodle', 'sherylcrowe', 10000, 32, 'sha512');
```

Creating a key with the password, `prancy poodle`, salt it with `sherylcrowe`, iterate 10,000 times, out put a 32 byte long key (AES-256-CBC needs that length).

## Step 2: Encrypt something

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, 'dogsarefun'.toString("binary"));

var crypted = cipher.update('wherearemysocks?');
crypted = Buffer.concat([crypted, cipher.final()]);
```

## Step 3: Decrypt & Fail

```
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, 'dogsarefun'.toString('binary'));

var decrypted = decipher.update(crypted);
decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Error (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:150:26)
    at repl:1:48
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:272:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:441:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:219:10)
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems so right, but is so wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply an IV for CBC mode and it needs to be block size (16-bytes for AES). 'dogsarefun' is only 10-bytes so the remaining bytes are unspecified and may (probably are) garbage.

Since PKCS padding is the default and CBC mode is used an incorrect IV will result in incorrect padding on decryption probably with the error: *routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt*.

P.S. Beware: This is the Internet which is pwned by cats.

Comment: Is there a good reference for what length keys and ivs different algorithms need?

Comment: Good point, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) provides the key sizes and block size but fails to mention that the IV size is the same as the block size, to much is assumed. There are several good books such as [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/index.html) see free download
*Applied Cryptography* by Bruce Schneier
*Practical Cryptography* by Niels Ferguson and Bruce Schneier
*Cryptography Decrypted* by H. X. Mel and Doris M. Baker (good starter I really like).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the createDecipheriv function to decrypt, and your IV must be 16 characters.

Example:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var buffer = require('buffer');

var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('prancypoodle', 'sherylcrowe', 10000, 32, 'sha512');

// Initialization vector must be 16 characters.
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key,
  new Buffer('1234567812345678', 'binary'));

var crypted = cipher.update('wherearemysocks?');
console.log('Encrypted: %s', crypted);
crypted = Buffer.concat([crypted, cipher.final()]);
// Again, IV must be 16 characters.
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key,
  new Buffer('1234567812345678', 'binary'));

var decrypted = decipher.update(crypted);
console.log('Decrypted: %s', decrypted);
```

Output:

```
Encrypted: #�j���(����
Decrypted: wherearemysocks?
```

Comment: It is really better to display encrypted data in hexadecimal as many (most) bytes are not printable characters. Something such as "#�j���(����" is rather meaningless since so many bytes are missing.

Comment: Ah, I mostly did it to demonstrate that it was once obscured (because it's encrypted!) and now is not. :P